# How to find the computer's domain programatically

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

Most of the systems currently are attached to a domain or so. Is there any method/system call I can make to get the system current domain (Something similar to gethostname). I am mainly looking for some portable solution (win/Lin) but if you can direct me how I can get the info in Linux it will be greatly helpful. I am trying to acquire the same in a C++ program in Linux, but have not yet been able.

Just to clarify, I know we can get the hostname easily. It the "somedomain" part of the "localhost@somedomain" I am looking for.

Comment: Not all Linux systems take part in any sort of Windows domain at all.

Comment: How about the case the system is connected to a wifi router. Will it acquire the wifi ssid as domain ?

Comment: no, Windows domains are totally different and unconnected to WiFi. (There's a minor caveat there with WPA Enterprise)

Comment: While googling, i came across the file /etc/resolv.conf which has the domain key and value. I am checking if i can get that value (if present) through an api other than through reading through the file.

Comment: Ah that's the source of confusion then - it's not related to workgroups at all, but it is still a domain.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `getdomainname()` function, that gets the DNS domain name of your computer (not the workgroup/Windows domain), e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[1024];
  getdomainname(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```